# Passport throws a 500 internal server error at every request

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm at a complete loss with this. I can only assume it's passport because when I comment out its initialization everything magically works again. I have 2 routes currently setup. One is a get request that requires a user to be logged in and the other is a post request that actually does the logging in.

in my app.js file my passport setup looks like this:

```
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

//handles cookie/session creation
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionKey,
    resave: false,
    store:sessionStore,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        //secure: true,
        maxAge:24*60*60*1000 //1 day in milliseconds
    }
}));
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
require('./services/passport');

//initiate route handlers
app.use('/login', require('./routes/authRoutes'));
app.use('/tiles', require('./routes/tileRoutes'));
```

I am using a local strategy as my users won't be using any kind of social app to login. I configured another file passport.js to actually handle the passport setup. I am using the sequelize database in order to verify users. This whole process looks like this:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done)=>{
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    const db = require('../models');
    db.user.findOne({ where: {username: username} })
        .then((user)=>{
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false);
            }else{
                // if(user.dataValues.hashed_password === password)
                //     return done(null, user);
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.dataValues.hashed_password, function(err, res) {
                      if(res === true){
                          return done(null, user);
                      }else{
                          return done(null, err);
                      }
                });

            }
        });

}));
```

signing people up, creating the session, and storing the session id all seem to be happening, however when I start making get/post requests on my front end with axios (I'm using react) I continually get a internal server error. I've tried catching this in everyway I can think of, breaking at definite points, an console.logging out but I just get the same message:

```
[0] GET /tiles 500 8.049 ms - 2
[0] GET /tiles 500 2.757 ms - 2
```

or from the console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/tiles/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

the actual get request looks like this (i havent' put much in till I know it works):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', isLoggedIn, (req, res)=>{
    debugger;
    res.send({hi:'there'})
});


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    debugger;
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
        console.log('failure');
        res.redirect('/login')
}

module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deserializeUser` should call the function to find user by id here, then pass it to done, the first param is `userId` as `serializeUser` return the `user.id` to session store. Example:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
  });
});
```